Korean TV show, dubbed in Arabic
While learning Arabic, one of my teachers would bring in a show on her thumb drive about a time in Korea when Imperial China seemed poised to invade while (what I think) was a civil war was happening. The Arabic dub was professionally acted out, and in Modern Standard Arabic. The show seemed really well produced, and possibly made just post 2000. I don't remember if the aspect ratio was 4:3 or not, it quite possibly was, but I think it was near 16:10, or was filmed in such a way to have sweeping views. One particular episode stands out, from what I'm certain was the first season of the show, in its first five or six episodes.
About half of this show happened in a battlefield, and the other in more courtly settings.
I remember the battlefield scenes were quite intense and well filmed. One particularly vivid scene had a team of men trying to sneak through tall grass at night, in hills, near what looked to be water or a swamp. They were wearing uniforms  with light armor. They spoke a pass phrase to a sentry involving the word "moon" and went through a small concealed door in the side of the hill. Later that night, when making their way back though the tall grass they were suddenly ambushed, one was killed with arrows, and the enemies were bearing torches, pursuing them.
The episode ended in the court, with something about some sort of deal over seas, (the details of which I don't recall - it may have been a trade deal, or something about marrying off a royal princess) and ended with a scene of a red sunset silhouetting what may have been a ship, like a Chinese junk. 
I really hope some one can help figure out what this show is so that I can hopefully get another Arabic dub or at least enjoy the show all the way through. Thanks!

Hi, I would be happy to help you finding the show, but do you remember any names of the character from the show?

@HongYunKim sadly no, I saw it almost 10 years ago.

There are quite a few Korean historical dramas that were dubbed into Arabic. I don't know enough about them to know if they match your description or not, but here are the ones that seem to be the better matches:
The King of Legend (aired as صراع الملوك)

The story of King Geunchogo, warrior king of Baekje. Under his reign, the kingdom experienced its glory days, with military conquests that saw him controlling most of the Korean peninsula and a subsequent enhancement of political power that reached its greatest height in Baekje's history.


The Kingdom of Wind (aired as أرض الريح)

The drama about the life of Jumong's grandson, Moo Hyul, who was born with a curse to kill his parent, siblings, son and destroy Goguryeo.



I will check these out and get back to you!

Those are in the vein of the show, but sadly they are too new. King of Legend first aired in 2010, and Kingdom of Wind, closer to my timeframe, was made in 2008 and still too new.
